# System.out.println from code being tested not appearing in TestNG output

Tags: java, java-8, testng

I have some code that has System.out.println("blah"). I am testing with TestNG. If I put a System.out.println in the blocks annotated with @Test, they appear in the test output. Nothing appears from System.out.println()s from the code being tested. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community edition and the project is using Maven. Is there a way to get the inner code's println()s to show up in the tests?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're experiencing is due to the way the standard output (stdout) works in Java and how it interacts with testing frameworks like TestNG. When you run tests using TestNG or other testing frameworks, the output generated by the code under test (including System.out.println() statements) might not be immediately visible in the console because the testing framework captures and manages the output streams.

In your case, since you're using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition and Maven, here's what you can do to capture and display the System.out.println() statements from the code being tested:

1. Configure Maven Surefire Plugin (pom.xml): The Maven Surefire Plugin is responsible for running tests in your Maven project. You can configure it to redirect the standard output to the console so that your System.out.println() statements are visible during test execution.
2. In your project's pom.xml file, within the  section, add the following configuration:

```
xml

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
        <configuration>
            <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

This configuration (redirectTestOutputToFile) tells Surefire not to redirect the test output to files, which should help in displaying System.out.println() statements directly in the console.

3. Ensure TestNG Output Settings:
   In IntelliJ IDEA, go to File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Maven and make sure the Skip tests checkbox is unchecked. This ensures that IntelliJ is not skipping the test execution.

   Check Run Configuration:
   When you run your TestNG tests in IntelliJ IDEA, make sure you are using the appropriate run configuration that runs the tests under TestNG. You can create a TestNG run configuration if one doesn't already exist.

With these configurations in place, when you run your TestNG tests in IntelliJ IDEA using Maven, you should be able to see the System.out.println() statements from the code being tested in the console.

Remember that using print statements for debugging purposes might not be the most efficient approach in the long run. Consider using proper logging frameworks like Log4j or SLF4J for better control over logging levels and output destinations in your code.